# SharedPreferences not Saving even after commits

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a really simple activity where I am taking the value of SharedPrefs and incrementing it by 1 every time the program is created. Thus i would expect that this would keep incrementing when i open and close(back out) of the program. However it seems like the values aren't saving. I am using commit after each change.

```
public class SharedPreferencesActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public static final String PREFERENCE_FILENAME = "MyGamePreferences";  

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    int int_out = 0;
    SharedPreferences gameSettings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = gameSettings.edit();

    int_out = gameSettings.getInt("Username", 0);
    Log.e("Pre",Integer.toString(int_out));
    int_out = int_out + 1;
    Log.e("During",Integer.toString(int_out));
    prefEditor.putInt("UserName", int_out);
    prefEditor.commit();
    int_out  = gameSettings.getInt("Username", 0);

    Log.e("Post",Integer.toString(int_out));

}
}
```

The output of my code above from the Log.e statments is

Pre: 0
During: 1
Post: 999

so it seems like after

```
calling prefEditor.commit();
int_out  = gameSettings.getInt("Username", 0);
```

the SharedPref gameSettings was not saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used one key with upper case letter. Change the line

```
prefEditor.putInt("UserName", int_out);
```

to

```
prefEditor.putInt("Username", int_out);
```